# Texts are not beside each other in two spans

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have texts in two spans, but they are not beside each other. (The last text is below the previous text, but it should be beside the previous.)

Here is the code from where the texts are printed:

```
var display_options_1 = `

         <td><span id="A${i}" class="${question.questionId}" onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[0]}</span><span>${question.option_text[0]}</span></td>
         <td><span id="B${i}" class="${question.questionId}" onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[1]}</span><span>${question.option_text[1]}</span></td>`;

var display_options_2 = `

         <td><span id="C${i}" class="${question.questionId}" onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[2]}</span><span>${question.option_text[2]}</span></td>
         <td><span id="D${i}" class="${question.questionId}" onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[3]}</span><span>${question.option_text[3]}</td>`;
```

Here is the [**full code**](http://jsbin.com/legipukuvu/1/edit?html,css,js,output) with a working [**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/qabuduqazo/)!

**UPDATE 1**

It was easier to solve the problem with [Static Void's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51049911/9836106), but I need only **`${question.options[]}`** to be selected not `${question.option_text[0]}`...

Comment: This is invalid markup. You never closed your spans

Comment: `td`s aren't closed either

Comment: Thanx for the suggestions @bassxzero codes are updated with it, by the way is there a specific reason of downvoting?

Comment: I downvoted because your question because of the invalid markup.

Answer (score 0):

still editing one moment  http://jsbin.com/zizelebiko/1/edit?js,output

```
  var display_options_1 = `

        var display_options_1 = `

        <td><div class="${question.questionId}"><span id="A${i}"  onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[0]}</span><span>${question.option_text[0]}</span></div></td>
        <td><div class="${question.questionId}"><span id="B${i}"  onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[1]}</span><span>${question.option_text[1]}</span></div></td>
    </td>`;
var display_options_2 = `

        <td><div class="${question.questionId}"><span id="C${i}"  onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[2]}</span><span>${question.option_text[2]}</span></div></td>
        <td><div class="${question.questionId}"><span id="D${i}"  onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[3]}</span><span>${question.option_text[3]}</span></div></td>
    </td>`;
```

Comment: But I need only `${question.options[]}` to be selected not `${question.option_text[0]}`...

Comment: @user9836106 oh yea i see what you mean, one moment

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this :
`<td><span id="A${i}" class="${question.questionId}" onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[0]}${question.option_text[0]}</span></td>`

Only one span is required.